# Reading Json file C# with dictionary or list inside as a value

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this json file:

```
[{
    "images": "hello", 
    "id": [{"value": 0, "url": "https://en.wikipedia", "content": "Since 200"}], 
    "answers": ["whole."], 
    "type": "description", 
    "row": "what is rba"
},
{
    "images": "hello2", 
    "id": [{"value": 1, "url": "https://en.wikipedia2", "content": "Since 2002"}], 
    "answers": ["whole."], 
    "type": "description2", 
    "row": "what is rba2"
}]
```

I need to read this file and store each key in a list. I have tried two different approaches:

The first approach I tried was:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string filePath = @"C:\Users\corve\OneDrive\Escritorio\file.json";
    string jsonString;
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        jsonString = streamReader2.ReadToEnd();
    }
    dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

    var urls = new List<string>();            

    foreach (var file in result.id)
    {
        urls.Add(file.url);
    }

    foreach (var item in urls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then the second approach was:

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
JsonTextReader JTextreader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);

JTextreader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
while (JTextreader.Read())
{
    if (JTextreader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        Passeges p = serializer.Deserialize<Passeges>(JTextreader);
        Console.WriteLine(p.type + " "+ p.row + " " );
    }
}
```

where:

```
class Passeges
{

    public string images { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string answers { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string row { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }    
}
```

However both resulted in errors. The first one:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'id''

and the second one:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '[0].id', line 3, position 8.'

Any Idea how to solve it or do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response[]>(jsonString);

            var urls = new List<string>();

            foreach (var response in result)
            {
                foreach (var id in response.id)
                {
                    urls.Add(id.url);
                    Console.WriteLine(id.url);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And your model objects should be:

```
        public class Response
        {
            public string images { get; set; }
            public Url[] id { get; set; }
            public string[] answers { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string row { get; set; }
        }

        public class Url
        {
            public int value { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string content { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The model is not in the correct format. I suggest you to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the `JSON` to `Class` and use `DeserializeObject` to get the result.

```
    public class Id
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject2
    {
        public string images { get; set; }
        public List<Id> id { get; set; }
        public List<string> answers { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string row { get; set; }
    }
```

and since id is within results, you need another `foreach` to get the URL

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\RnD\test.json";
        string jsonString;
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            jsonString = streamReader2.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject2>>(jsonString);

        var urls = new List<string>();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            foreach (var id in result.id)
            {
                urls.Add(id.url);
            }               
        }

        foreach (var item in urls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using two classes to parse your json like this?

```html
public class Id
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string images { get; set; }
    public List<Id> id { get; set; }
    public List<string> answers { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string row { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About your first approach, **result** is an array. I think you should do something like:

```
foreach(var r in result) {
  foreach(var file in r.id) {
    urls.Add(file.url);
  {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way of retrieving the urls without the need of having to declare a custom class

```
JArray data = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath));

List<string> urls = new List<string>();

foreach (JObject item in data.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JObject address in item.Property("id").Value.Children<JObject>())
    {
        urls.Add(address.Property("url").Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is the code above formatted into a handy one-liner

```
var urls = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath)).Children<JObject>()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Property("id").Value.Children<JObject>()
        .Select(y => y.Property("url").Value.ToString()))
            .ToList();
```